# Does a reboot of Ubuntu cover all CA actions that an update-ca-certificates would do?

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-20.04, podman

When I copy a new CA certificate, e.g., `mycompany.crt` into the directory `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, I have to do an `update-ca-certificates` in order to make this certificate known to the system.

My question is: Is this command always necessary or would a `reboot` do the same thing?
In particular, does Ubuntu pick up all certificate files in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` during booting and make them known to the system?

One use case where this is also important is when working with containers. It would be interesting to know if, e.g., a mere

```
docker run \
--mount type=bind,source=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates,target=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates,readonly \
my_image
```

would be enough, or if I need a

```
docker run \
--mount type=bind,source=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates,target=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates,readonly \
my_image update-ca-certificates
```

provided that `my_image` is an Ubuntu based image that has the apt package `ca-certificate` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Running `update-ca-certificates` is not covered by rebooting your linux machine.
It's usually automatically run when other software packages install new certificates to the cert store. But, again, not at reboot time.